# First and last date for a user

Tags: date, ms-access

user id date

```
1   4/4/2012
1   4/3/2011
1   2/11/2009
2   6/17/2013
2   3/13/1998
3   7/8/2001
4   12/12/2012
4   11/11/2011
4   12/19/1999
5   4/6/2006
5   9/30/2008
6   2/28/2005
6   4/5/2004
6   2/1/2003
6   6/7/2011
7   8/19/2002
7   6/7/2001
7   9/5/2010
```

I am using access. How do I get the first and last date for each user?

Answer (score 0):

Use Group By and Min, Max

```
SELECT userdates.Id, Min(userdates.Date) AS MinDate, Max(userdates.Date) AS MaxDate
FROM userdates
GROUP BY userdates.Id;
```